# getting error on newly created project with azurefunctions using visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure-functions

I'm new to .net and azurefunctions. i'm trying to create a project with azure functions in visual studion on every newly created project it throwing error. do i need to configure anything to getrid of these errors.

[image]s

Answer (score 0):

When you've only just created the project, the code hasn't been built yet. Any NuGet packages your code is using haven't been downloaded yet. Those are the red squiggly lines you're seeing.

Build the project by either clicking the Build menu and selecting Build solution, by right clicking the solution/project and selecting Build or by using the `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `B` keys. This will not only build your code, but also restore any packages that are being referenced.

To manually (only) restore packages, either run `dotnet restore` from a command line in the folder of the solution/project or right click the solution and select Restore NuGet packages.